# In Jinja2, how to create auto increment numbers?

Tags: jinja2

In a page, I want to display some figures with text prompt. For example:

```
Figure 1
Figure 2
```

My code is

```
{% set num = 0 %}
Figure {{ ++num }}
Figure {{ ++num }}
```

But it shows

```
Figure 0
Figure 0
```

How can I make it fulfil my expectations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either those *text prompt* are in a list already, and you can use a `for` to display them, along with `loop.index` for the numbering:

```
{% set texts = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] %}

{%- for text in texts -%}
  Figure {{ loop.index }}
  {{ text }}

{% endfor -%}
```

Will render

```
Figure 1
  foo

Figure 2
  bar

Figure 3
  baz
```

Or, they are in another format and you will have to use a `set` to increment your counter:

```
{% set foo = 'foo' -%}
{% set bar = 'bar' -%}
{% set baz = 'baz' -%}
{% set counter = 1 -%}

Figure {{ counter }}
  {{ foo }}

{% set counter = counter + 1 -%}
Figure {{ counter }}
  {{ bar }}

{% set counter = counter + 1 -%}
Figure {{ counter }}
  {{ baz }}
```

Which will render the same.